# how to correctly update all data in the Mongodb via updateMany?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

```
        const filterId = await this.extractValue(query, 'id');
        const activeChange = await this.productModel.updateMany(
          { _id: filterId },
          { $set: { active: false} },
        );
```

this method updates one record by id, i need it to get an array of objects and update the whole Mongodb database with them, tell me how to implement this? thanks in advance

Comment: use `updateOne` instead of `updateMany` if query contains ` _id`